# What should be my geom_text aesthetics for y in my ggplot2 codes in this context?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have the following `ggplot2` codes running in `RStudio`:

```
p2 <- ggplot(subset(df1,LEVEL %in% c("FM")),aes(x=los_group)) +
    ggtitle("FM: % of Respondents by Length of Service") + xlab("LOS Group") +
    geom_bar(aes(y = 100*(..count..)/sum(..count..)), width = 0.5, fill="steelblue") + 
    ylab("Percentage") +
    geom_text(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust= 1.5, 
    vjust=0.5, angle = 90, color="white", fontface="bold", size=6)+
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_minimal()

p2
```

I want to insert the percentage values (with the % sign) inside the bars (at the top end). I am stuck at specifying the `y` aesthetics in my `geom_text` codes.

Currently, I am getting the following error message:

```
Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: y, label
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using standard data, since we don't have your `df1`.

When I'm using a calculation in multiple places, it's often easiest to calculate it prior to ggplot and pipe it in, where it will be interpreted as the first (ie data) term of the `ggplot` call.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Calculate share of counts per cylinder, and pipe that into ggplot
mtcars %>%
  count(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n)) %>%

  # Declare global x, y, and label mapping. If not specifically specified
  #   in subsequent `geoms`, they will adopt these. 
  ggplot(aes(x=cyl, y = share, label = scales::percent(share, accuracy = 1))) +
  ggtitle("FM % of Respondents by Length of Service") + 
  xlab("LOS Group") +
  geom_col(width = 0.8, fill="steelblue") + 
  ylab("Percentage") +
  geom_text(position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust= 0.5, 
            vjust=-0.5, angle = 90, color="white", fontface="bold", size=6) +
  coord_flip() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have the x-axis labels to show as 0, 10, 20 and so on (instead of 0.0, 0.1 and 0.2...)?

Comment: add `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +`

Comment: or you can add smth like this: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 0.5, .1), labels = glue::glue("{seq(0, 50, 10)}%"))`

Comment: @JonSpring Thanks. Running your above codes "as is"  (with the mtcars dataset) is giving me this error:
Error in scales::percent(share, accuracy = 1) : 
  unused argument (accuracy = 1)

Comment: You might have an old version of the `scales` package? I think the syntax changed in the last year or so.